# Objective-C : CoreData and MapKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, mapkit

I have in coredata attribute longitude and latitude type Double. Name entities AddMan. I create class usersIndex for singleton

```
.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import "AddMan.h"

//OutgoingUser
@interface usersIndex : NSObject

//@property (nonatomic) AddMan* user;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *longtitude;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *latitude;

+ (usersIndex *)sharedManager;
+ (void) del;

@end
```

and in my `.m`

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "usersIndex.h"

@interface usersIndex ( )
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *context;

@end

@implementation usersIndex

 static usersIndex *sharedMyManager = nil;

+ (usersIndex *)sharedManager {

    static dispatch_once_t once;

    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        sharedMyManager = [usersIndex new];

    });
    return sharedMyManager;
}

+ (void) del {

    sharedMyManager.longtitude = NULL;
    sharedMyManager.latitude = NULL;

}
```

I create ViewController and hooked MapKit. In my class i need show all markers from coredata. How can I implement this?
I have a version of how this can be done but I do not quite understand it.

```
for (int i = 0; i <_users.count; i ++) {
     _index = i;
    
     CustomMKPointAnnotation * myAnnot = [[CustomMKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
     NSManagedObject * obj = [_users objectAtIndex: _index];
     theCoordinate.latitude = [[obj valueForKey: @ "lantitude"] doubleValue];
     theCoordinate.longitude = [[obj valueForKey: @ "longitude"] doubleValue];
     myAnnot.coordinate = theCoordinate;
     myAnnot.indexAnnotation = i;
     myAnnot.title = [NSString stringWithFormat: @ "% @", [obj valueForKey: @ "name"]];
     myAnnot.subtitle = [NSString stringWithFormat: @ "% @", [obj valueForKey: @ "lastname"]];
    
     [Self.totalMapView addAnnotation: myAnnot];
}
```

Then he even with the withdrawal of Custom annotations by clicking. I somewhat understand what you need to create a separate class with an array into which to place it. And in class MapVS output through a cycle which is shown above. Does anyone have ideas of how to use this code.